# Where to start in profiling SQL server Silverlight application

Tags: sql-server, silverlight

I need some advice on where to start in profiling a silverlight 3 application that is loading data from a SQL server Express database.

At this stage I am not sure if the querying of the data  on the server is taking long (and we may need indexes) or if loading on the client side is the problem.

How would one start?

JD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full edition Profiler can connect to Express and it can monitor it's execution. Another venue is to use the DMVs, specially [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) and [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx). The former gives information about past query execution time, whether the query was CPU bound or not, how much IO it performed. The later gives information about currently executing queries, specially what they are currently waiting on and how much IO they are performing. It takes a good understanding of things SQLish to interpret the results, but all the information is out there in the DMVs and they can be queried on Express using any query tool, like Express's lite SSMS or even from [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).